# Core data relationship: When fetching, do you automatically get second entity through relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, attributes, relationship

I want to retrieve an attribute from an entity to which the entity I am querying is connected via a one to one relationship.  I am fetching an object first in a table view using NSFetchedResultsController and then, if you select a row of the table, through prepareforsegue.

In the prepareforsegue in the tableviewcontroller, the item in question is identified through its index path and the destination view controller gets the object with the following code:

```
Items *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
IDDetailVC *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.item=item;
```

Then in the detail or destination view controller, I have access to all the attribute of the item object through `self.item.attribute1` etc.

My question is, what is right way to create relationship with second entity, say Addresses, to get an attribute from it?  I have tried `item.address` and it throws an error while `address.address` is null.

Comment: To confirm, that you can access `item` attributes means that your detail / destination view controller has an `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: you mean I need allocated it in viewdidload?

Comment: Your detail / destination view controller needs an `NSManagedObjectContext` to interact with other entities. Do you set this in your detail / destination view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that you do not get this automatically but need to set it upon creating the item with newItem.otherInfo = otherInfo.name.